# Xamarin.iOS label displaced on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a custom TableViewCell with 2 UILabels, which should be aligned to the left and right (label itself and it's content) and get some unexpected behaviour on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus.

This is how it looks on iPhone 6 (bad):
[image]

This is how it looks on iPhone 5 and should look like on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus (good):
[image]

My current implementation is just a simple custom cell with two labels, which text are aligned to the left and right. I tried adding constraints for both UILabels, but nothing changes, right UILabel is still being displaced. This is how it looks like in Xamarin Studio Interface Builder:

[image]

What should I do to achieve same behaviour on all devices?

Answer (score 0):

Enable AutoLayout, Set leading and trailing spaces constraints for both labels and it should look the same in all devices. (from your screenshot, it doesn't seem that constraints are set).

If you still have issues positioning, make sure it looks correct in Interface Builder rather than Xamarin Studio. I had some positioning issues with that so I always use Interface Builder.